# Python is not able to read the file

Tags: python, postgresql

Let me rephrase the question. The equal signs are in the code, i hope that this is showed in the following lines of code. Apparently it does not read any of the tables that are stored in the sql database, which i can find however when I look at pgadmin. Do any of you have any idea what the reason could be that it cannot read any of the tables that are mentioned in this code. The strange thing is that I can read this code in pgadmin, however.

Thanks!

```
createjointable = '''SELECT( 
financial_data."Municipality",  
    financial_data."Average_income_per_working_person", 
    financial_data."Average_income_per_working_population",     
    financial_data."Average_income_per_household",
    fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns."postcode",
    fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns."place_name",
    fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns."county_name",
    fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns."state_name",
    fundadata."postcode")
FROM "fundadata"
INNER JOIN "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns"
    ON "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns"."postcode" = "fundadata"."postcode"
INNER JOIN "financial_data"
    ON  "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns"."place_name" = "financial_data"."Municipality";'''

cursor.execute(createjointable);
    INNER JOIN financial_data
        ON financial_data."Municipality" "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns"."postcode")'''


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UndefinedTable                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-9d480b2d2e54> in <module>
     15     ON  "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns"."place_name" = "financial_data"."Municipality";'''
     16 
---> 17 cursor.execute(createjointable);

UndefinedTable: relation "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns" does not exist
LINE 12: INNER JOIN "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns"
                    ^
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: UndefinedTable: relation "fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns" does not exist
That's a pretty clear problem. What's the real name of the table you're looking for? And don't use UPPERcase in your SQL and names. If you don't, you don't need double quotes " either.

Comment: This '...cannot read any of the tables...' is not true. It is finding `"fundadata"`.  Best guesses as to why `"fundadata_zip_converter_dropped_columns"` is not found: 1) The name is mixed/upper case and is not being quoted correctly 2) There is a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue and the table needs to be schema qualified. FYI, this `cursor.execute(createjointable); INNER JOIN financial_data ...` is not correct.